# jQuery datetimepicker saves to database with month/day reverse

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I've seen this issue on other SO threads but haven't found a solution which works for me yet. I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class='col-xs-12'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Ends At</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='ends_at'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" name='schedule_item[ends_at]' value=''/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ends_at').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I've played with formatting a ton. I pick a date and the value "01/09/2017 12:00 AM" comes up. In my database this is saved as "2017-09-01 04:00:00". When I print date as string I get "September 01 2017" confirming I know the date is incorrectly saved to my database. Anyone have any tips? Thanks

Comment: Please provide more detail. It would be helpful to see what is being posted to the server as well as what the receiving function and database call look like. In addition, note the culture of the client doing the post.

Answer (score 0):

> The **DATE** type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays **DATE** values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01'` to `'9999-12-31'`.
>
> The **DATETIME** type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays **DATETIME** values in `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. The supported range is `'1000-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'9999-12-31 23:59:59'`.
>
> The **TIMESTAMP** data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. **TIMESTAMP** has a range of `'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC` to `'2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC`.

[MySQL Reference - DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

---

- MySQL dictates how you'll store and retrieve the date and time values.
- Delegate the date/time formatting to your server/client code.